# regex : match string with invert pattern preceeding the other pattern

Tags: python, regex

this is the code :

`(?!cxdef\.)trimheader`

i want it to match any : `'=trimheaderspace' or 'old.trimheader' or 'get trimheader()'` etc...  but **NOT  "... = cxdef.trimheaderspace()"**

i don't want a 'cxdef.' preceeding the 'trimheader'.

It looks so simple , but the code won't work . any idea ?

Comment: use a lookbehind, not a lookahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a zero width negative lookbehind:

```
>>> def out_match(st):
...     return st if re.search(r'(?<!cxdef\.)trimheader', st) else None
... 
>>> out_match('=trimheaderspace')
'=trimheaderspace'
>>> out_match('cxdef.trimheaderspace()')
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my question , here the code :

```
(?<!cxdef\.)trimheader
```

i just add `<` inbetween the `?` and `!` to make negative lookbehind. it will match anything other than 'cxdef.trimheader'.

Comment: Have you checked the already provided answer? This is exactly what the given answer mentioned..

Comment: Thanks , i got this answer before i read your post. Actually i got it from here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIEjh0YsxWA . it's a simple Lookahead tutorial video. Thanks

Comment: also here the good tool to play with which used in that video  : http://regexr.com/v1/  
made by http://gskinner.com